# Reputation gain on getting voted up or down

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes

Should we still use +10 rep, +5 rep on a voted up answer&questions with a negative scores?

The problem is:

If the answer got a -5 score because it's really bad, they lose 10 rep. But after that, someone voted the answer up (maybe accidentally or just being kind) the answerer got +10 rep, so they didn't lose any of the rep. That means they don't quite receive their punishments.

I really don't think so because added rep should be calculated from the total score of the post, not the calculation of vote up = +10 vote down = -2. Also, we may need a check of voting up on a bad post by using the community score. Because some vote up are caused by exchanging votes, and we don't have punishment on that.

Comment: This is the example, I wrote this comment while my question got -2 score , but in summary I got +5 reps because someone voted me up , haha just being funny

Comment: Heh. That has a good reason on Meta though, where people often vote to express disagreement with a suggestion like this one (rather than punish for a low quality post like mostly on SO)

Comment: We're working to nullify the up-vote. Just give us more time...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good to know that we are working on it, thanks

Comment: What about just increasing the answer downvote to -3 reputation?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Oh , maybe. But it's not up to me :) , it's those "Moderators" to judge what is good for the site.

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years: currently, a downvote on an answer makes the answerer lose 2 reputation. Since you get more reputation for an upvote on an answer, why not make it 3 reputation lost instead of 2?

Answer (score 7):

I see your point and it's not wrong. But the balance is arguably still ok and shouldn't be changed.

The role of downvotes is to call attention to a problem, rather than eradicating someone's reputation.

Even with the small reputation loss, downvotes hurt and are a frequent source of complaints and drama.

It is true that occasionally, many dumb upvotes give a user an unjustified rep gain. Your suggestion would help cancel out that effect and that isn't bad thinking.

But this occasional "unfair enrichment" is something that we as a community are willing to live with, for the sake of a system that is, by and large, very welcoming and motivating new users to "play".

Also, the current balance allows you to reach a net reputation gain if you improve your contribution's quality, which is an important incentive to fix things that the community thinks have a problem.

Comment: You have a very good reason,But I disagree that this is for new users to "play", well it should be. But did you see what do high reps users do to new users? Every one that is new to this site request "help". But we just marked them "duplicate","off-topic","not belong here".Eventhough, old questions that are marked duplicate got really high score. If you were a new user like I was a few months ago, will you still "play"able in that condition? When you reach high level in the site(high reps), most of the people will agree with you more thana low level user.

Comment: @Poomrokc it's partly true that high-reputation users get less scrutiny from their fellow users - but how would increasing the rep punishment from downvotes improve the situation for new users?

Comment: It's a new arguments , I forgot so say so